# Python - How to continue if json element not found

Tags: python, json, try-catch

So I have been playing around with Json and some comparing.

So basically I have a Json where some element are included in some elements and some don't.

The issue I am having is that the script continues the script over and over but never does anything due to exception where it can't find the elements etc *Price*, *estimatedLaunchDate* which will be found in this Json

```
sample = {
"threads": [{
        "seoTitle": "used food",
        "other_crap": "yeet"
    },
    {
        "seoTitle": "trucks",
        "other_crap": "it's a fox!"
        "product": {
            "imageUrl": "https://imagerandom.jpg",
            "price": {
                "fullRetailPrice": 412.95
            },
            "estimatedLaunchDate": "2018-06-02T03:00:00.000",
            "publishType ": "DRAW"
        },
        {
            "seoTitle": "rockets",
            "other_crap": "i'm rocket man"
        },
        {
            "seoTitle": "helicopter",
            "other_crap": "for 007"
            "product": {
                "imageUrl": "https://imagerandom.jpg",
                "price": {
                    "fullRetailPrice": 109.95
                },
                "estimatedLaunchDate": "2018-06-19T00:00:00.000",
                "publishType": "FLOW"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

as you can see there is some extra information in some of the json elements than the other and there is the issue I am having, What/how can I make it so it continues or just adds etc *"Price not found"*, *"publishType not found"* and still continue the rest of the json?

I have made a code that does this so far:

```
old_list = []

    while True:
        try:
            resp = requests.get("www.helloworld.com")
            new_list = resp.json()['threads']

            for item in new_list:

                newitemword = item['seoTitle']

                if newitemword not in old_list:
                    try:

                        print(newitemword) #item name

                        print(str(item['product']['price']['fullRetailPrice']))
                        print(item['product']['estimatedLaunchDate']) 
                        print(item['product']['publishType']) 


                        old_list.append(newitemword)



                    except Exception as e:
                        print(e)
                        print("ERROR")
                        time.sleep(5)
                        continue


            else:
                randomtime = random.randint(40, 60)
                time.sleep(randomtime)
```

As you can see there is 4 prints inside the try except method and if one of those 3 (fullRetailPrice, estimatedLaunchDate, publishType) it will throw a exception and will not continue the rest of the code meaning it will already die after the  `"seoTitle": "trucks",` element!

Comment: when you use `['foo']` to get the element at `'foo'` from a dictionary, it will raise a KeyError if that element isn't found. If instead you use `d.get('foo')` then that method will return `None` (or another default value you provide) if the key `'foo'` isn't found.  Using that, you can remove the try-except block by checking if the return value from `get` is None or not.  I can write up an example if needed.

Comment: @BowlingHawk95 I would like to have a example if you have a spare time! I would really appreciate it ! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I won't rewrite your whole example, but suppose that when you lookup the value

```
print(str(item['product']['price']['fullRetailPrice']))
```

one or more of those keys you follow might not be there.  You could detect this in code by doing

```
foo = item.get('product', {}).get('price', {}).get('fullRetailPrice')
if foo:
    print(str(foo))
else:
    print('Retail price could not be found')
```

The second parameter to `get` is the value to return if the desired key can't be found.  Making this return an empty dictionary `{}` will let you keep checking down the line until the end.  The last `get` will return `None` if any of the keys aren't found.  You can then check if `foo` is None and print an error message appropriately.

Comment: Thank you very much! I have a question if I might ask? Etc - lets say if I don't find value of fullRetailPrice and publishType, would I need to do another if else statement for each element?

Comment: That sort of depends on the structure of the data you're walking and the logic you want to have.  You could write your code to `continue` to the next `item` in the list at the first failure, or keep going with the current `item`.  It's really up to you, but you'll probably want one of these if-else blocks per path you try to walk, since I'm guessing that you want to check each path down the object independently of each other.

Comment: Oh yeah, I mean it does work with the if else statement and as you said, I do want to keep going on with the current `item` of course. but I thought maybe there is more "flexible" way etc using nested dictionary values but I don't know if that would fit my "thread" that im trying to do now?